# Is it possible to do an "inverse/symmetrical difference fill" for polygons in QGIS, i.e. fill everything BUT the polygons?

Tags: qgis, visualisation, fill, symmetric-difference

I often deal with polygons that delineate an area of interest. When visualizing them, I have the problem that:

1. using a fill "masks" the content of the area of interest, e.g. a background raster layer
2. using an outline isn't clear/unambigous in showing what's inside and outside, especially with complex geometries

I presume this is a common dilemma, so I was wondering:

**Is there a convenient function to do an "inverse fill" in QGIS?**

Materializing the symmetrical difference and using that for visualization is a solution (that is what I did for below screenshots), but isn't really convenient, given that now I have to use different files for calculations and visualization (and calculating the symmetrical difference takes surprisingly long).

To show what I mean, this is what I have:

Polygons, **visualized with outline**. This is ambigous: Do i mean the forested (dark) or unforested (brighter) area?
[image: polygons with outline]

**With a fill**, it is clear which area is meant, but now my area of interest is "covered" (to some extent, could be less with transparency and such, but then the highlight isn't as powerful):
[image: polygons with fill]

**With an "inverse fill"**, I have the desired effect: The area of interest is fully clear, everything else is masked.
[image: polygons with inverse fill]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `style` tab, instead of selecting `unique symbol`

[image]

select `inverted polygons`

[image]

You can also apply a partial opacity to it (or a pattern fill, if desired), so the features underneath are also visible.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I consider this circumstantial and not convenient, but it is a way to achieve it (used for the last screenshot), so for completeness I'll post it here as an answer:

1. Create a new polygon "*vis_area*" that encompasses the whole area to visualize (a single filled rectangle)
2. Calculate the `symmetrical difference` between *vis_area* and *area_of_interest*.
3. Use the *result.shp* for visualization with a fill.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by @JesúsPinilla is the way to go. However, just to show another way how to do it - including the possibility to create this either just for visualization without creating a new layer (using [Geometry generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#the-geometry-generator)), or creating it as actual geometries on a new layer with [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) ([see here for details about both options](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)).

Create an expression that:

1. Collects all the polygons
2. Creates a bounding box around the extent of the layer
3. Buffers this bounding box
4. Creates the difference: extraxts the polygons (no. 1) from the buffered bounding box (no. 3)

Use this expression (change the buffer size - here: `4000` - at the end of line 2 as you like):

```
difference (
    buffer (layer_property(@layer,'extent'), 4000),
    collect($geometry)
)
```

*The solution, used with Geometry generator to create the area with blue line fill pattern from the initial red polygons:*
[image]